# Destiny Generation Upgrade

Tags: destiny

Can i redeem the free upgrade for the Xbox One version on the Xbox website now although i dont have a Xbox One yet?

Comment: We can't answer this; we don't know what Microsoft will do after the time expires any better than you do.

Comment: ive added an easier question

Comment: If you have other question, create a **NEW** question.

Comment: The question you deleted was basically the same question just in some other words so you could give a clear answer and don't have to speculate.

Comment: You're better off removing the first question entirely, if you're set on re-using this question.  That looks like an answerable question, while your previous one isn't one we allow.

Answer (score 0):

No, the thing is that if you buy Destiny Digital copy **BEFORE** **January 15th**, when you get your new **Xbox One** you'll be able to download Destiny for free, it goes the same way with PS3 and PS4. For what I've read [**here**](http://www.destinythegame.com/digital-upgrade) you don't need to buy your **Xbox One before** **January 15th**, you just need to buy the Destiny digital copy before that date.

Comment: so the standard hard copy release doesn't include this free upgrade?

Comment: For what I've read it doesn't. @TankorSmash